# How to model these relationships using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, paypal, relationship

I have an Order model, a Seller model, and a Quote model. An order has many quotes, a seller has many quotes, and a quote belongs to an order and a seller.

Now I want to add a Payment model, which captures the payment for a quote. I have two options:

1. a payment has a quote_id and belongs to a quote. What troubles me is that I am not sure how to define the relationship between the seller and the payment using ActiveRecord. I want to use something like `@seller.payments` to list all payments that seller received. `@seller.quotes.joins(:payments)` might work, but it's ugly.
2. a payment has a seller_id and order_id, so the sellers have many payments. A payment can belong to a quote using the composite key [seller_id, order_id] (by using the composite-primary-key gem)

The thing is there might be other models that belongs to a quote, but the relationship with seller is more important (eg. Rating). This seems like a pretty common scenario. I wonder which option is better and if there're other more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your first option you can use

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotes
  has_many :payments, through: :quotes
end
```

Which will allow you to do `@seller.payments`

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if this works as well. But I didn't see any usage like this in the docs. The quotes table isn't a join table for sellers and payments (there is seller_id, but no payment_id).

Comment: @OnionBomb No, there's not but it works.  I'm amazed by the crazy stuff rails will let you do.

Comment: It does work. They should put these crazy stuffs in the docs.